SPDE Renormalization
some SPDE (in higher dimensions) can only be interpreted in a "renormalised" sense. For example considering $\Phi_2^4$ on $\mathbb{R}_+\times \mathbb{T}^d$ the solution is defined as the limit of $\phi_\epsilon:=u_\epsilon+X_\epsilon$ where $X_\epsilon(r)=\rho_\epsilon*X(r)$ is a mollified version of the stochastic convolution $X(r,g)=\int_0^r\int (p(r-q,\cdot)*g)(x)\xi(dq,dx)$ (defined in the distribution sense, where we also define as usual $X_{\epsilon}(r,x):=X_\epsilon(r,\rho_\epsilon(x-\cdot))$), $u_\epsilon$ solves $\partial_t u_\epsilon=\Delta u_\epsilon-u^3_\epsilon-u_\epsilon Y_\epsilon-X_\epsilon u_\epsilon^2-W_\epsilon,$ where $Y_\epsilon,W_\epsilon$ are 2 convenient Wick powers also defined in the distribution sense, we also have $Y_\epsilon(g)=\int_\mathbb{T^d} g (x)((X_\epsilon (x))^2-c_\epsilon)dx,Y_\epsilon(g)=\int_\mathbb{T^d} g(x) ((X_\epsilon (x))^3-3c_\epsilon X_\epsilon(x))dx,c_\epsilon$ is a convenient real number.
The following have been bothering me: for initial condition $h,$ the solution $\phi_\epsilon$ should then verify $\phi_\epsilon = P_rh-\int_0^rP_{r-q}(\phi_\epsilon^3-3c_\epsilon\phi_\epsilon)dq+X_\epsilon(r)$
BUT given that $Y_\epsilon(g)=\int g(x)((X_\epsilon (x))^2-c_\epsilon)dx,Y_\epsilon(g)=\int g(x)((X_\epsilon (x))^3-3c_\epsilon X_\epsilon(x))dx,c_\epsilon,$ we should instead obtain for a test function $g,\phi_\epsilon(g)=P_rh(g)-\int_{0}^rP_{r-q}(\int g(x) ((X_\epsilon(q,x)+u_\epsilon(g))^3-3c_\epsilon (q) X_\epsilon(r,x))dx)dq,$ which doesn't make sense (the following was helpful for Hermite polynomial $H_k(x+y,r)=\sum_{q=0}^kH_q(x,r)y^{k-q}$)
Something crucial is missing here, how to interpret $ \phi_\epsilon = P_rh-\int_0^rP_{r-q}(\phi_\epsilon^3(q)-3c_\epsilon(q)\phi_\epsilon(q))dq+X_\epsilon(r)$?

You simply did the algebra wrong. I suggest to forget about the mild formulation and the test function since they merely obscure the computation. For $\epsilon>0$ all the PDEs make sense pointwise, so you can do the algebra for the right-hand sides and you will get what you want.

@m7e 1. You mean $\phi_\epsilon = P_rh-\int_0^rP_{r-q}(\phi_\epsilon^3-3c_\epsilon\phi_\epsilon)dq+X_\epsilon(r)$
the solution is defined point wise (mild formulation)? How come this is true? 2. How to relate the equation verified by $u_\epsilon$,
defined in the distribution sense, to the equation verified by $\phi_\epsilon$,
defined pointwise?

Every object with an $\epsilon$ index is a smooth function. Nothing needs to be defined in the distributional sense at this stage (in the $\epsilon\to 0$ limit yes, but that is orthogonal to your question).
